# return documents with more terms in ElasticSearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I'm working on a project that needs elastic search to return the documents with more terms. I know from the official guide es will return with more exact document(which means returning matched docs but with fewer terms).

So is there any chance for me to sort in that way?

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking to sort results by the number of terms in the document?

Comment: yes. and actually I used a script to do it. But the tricky part is that our data model is of nested object. I could use _source to get the value in a nested object but it's gonna be too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort by the number of terms in a document, so as you suggested, you'd need some sort of script to compute that and attach it to each document as a field.

Sorting on nesting fields is not a problem though. Just refer to sort fields using dot notation - e.g. `outer_object.inner_object.number_of_terms`